# Custom horizontal Accordion using JQuery/JQuery UI - Width issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, horizontal-accordion

I've written a custom horizontal accordion using JQuery and JQuery UI. Previously I wrote vertical accordion using SlideUp and SlideDown and it worked perfectly well. In the sense, both of them got called simultaneously and so while one was sliding up (with its height reducing) the other one was sliding down (with its height increasing) and it was smooth.

But in horizontal accordion I have to slide left. So I use JQuery UI Toggle('slide') to do that. The two toggle functions are getting called simultaneously but the problem is that the WIDTH of the control is not reducing as it slides in. The width remains as it is since the full slide is completed and it is *getting hidden suddenly*.

Here is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Accordion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //temporary variables

        //append PCID at the end
        var currentOpenContent000;
        var pcid000 = '000';
        var time = 1000;
        var controlwidth = 600;
        var contentWidth = 400;
        var controlHeight = 400;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            autoScale();
            initializeControl();
            createEvents();
        });

        function autoScale() {
        }

        function setNormalsppheaderStyle(element) {
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': '#347235',
                'color': '#FFFFFF'
            });
        }

        function setHoversppheaderStyle(element) {
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': 'orange',
                'color': '#FFFFFF'
            });
        }

        function setSelectedsppheaderStyle(element) {
            $(element).css({
                'background-color': 'orange',
                'color': '#FFFFFF'
            });
        }

        function createEvents() {
            $('div[id*=header]').click(function () {
                if (currentOpenContent000 == $(this).attr('id').replace('header', 'content'))
                    return;

                //hide old item
                setNormalsppheaderStyle($('#' + currentOpenContent000.replace('content', 'header')));
                $('#' + currentOpenContent000).toggle('slide');

                var cHeader = $(this).attr('id');
                var cContent = $(this).attr('id').replace('header', 'content');

                //show new item
                setSelectedsppheaderStyle($(this));
                $('#' + cContent).toggle('slide');
                currentOpenContent000 = cContent;

            });

            $('div[id*=header]').mouseover(function () {
                setHoversppheaderStyle($(this));
            });

            $('div[id*=header]').mouseout(function () {
                if (currentOpenContent000 == $(this).attr('id').replace('header', 'content'))
                    return;
                setNormalsppheaderStyle($(this));
            });
        }

        function initializeControl() {
            var first = $('#' + pcid000 + 'content1');
            first.toggle('slide');
            currentOpenContent000 = pcid000 + 'content1';
            setSelectedsppheaderStyle($('#' + pcid000 + 'header1'));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 1px; float: left" id="000outer">
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
            <tr>
                <!--Loop this content-->
                <td>
                    <div id="000header1" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px;">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000content1" style="background-color: silver; width: 400px; height: 396px;
                        display: none">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000header2" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000content2" style="background-color: silver; width: 400px; height: 396px;
                        display: none">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000header3" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000content3" style="background-color: silver; width: 400px; height: 396px;
                        display: none">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000header4" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="000content4" style="background-color: silver; width: 400px; height: 396px;
                        display: none">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can save this markup and run it and check it. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, update your IDs with W3C documentation: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). Also, why do you use doble-wrapping? setSelectedsppheaderStyle($('#' + pcid000 + 'header1')); is already jQuery collection, and inside setSelectedsppheaderStyle you make $( element ) again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup was a bit strange, so I make little changes (I'm not an expert in CSS). Link to playground: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/8LNkG/6/

HTML:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 1px; float: left" id="outer">

    <div id="header1" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px; float:left; margin:1px;">
    </div>
    <div id="content1" style="background-color: silver; width: 0; height: 396px; float:left;">
    </div>
    <div id="header2" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px; float:left; margin:1px;">
    </div>
    <div id="content2" style="background-color: silver; height: 396px; float:left;">
    </div>
    <div id="header3" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px; float:left; margin:1px;">
    </div>
    <div id="content3" style="background-color: silver; height: 396px; float:left;">
    </div>
    <div id="header4" style="background-color: darkgreen; width: 30px; height: 396px; float:left; margin:1px;">
    </div>
    <div id="content4" style="background-color: silver; height: 396px; float:left;">
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
//temporary variables

//append PCID at the end
var currentOpenContent000;
var time = 1000;
var controlwidth = 600;
var contentWidth = 400;
var controlHeight = 400;

$(document).ready(function () {
    autoScale();
    initializeControl();
    createEvents();
});

function autoScale() {
}

function setNormalsppheaderStyle(element) {
    element.css({
        'background-color': '#347235',
        'color': '#FFFFFF'
    });
}

function setHoversppheaderStyle(element) {
    element.css({
        'background-color': 'orange',
        'color': '#FFFFFF'
    });
}

function setSelectedsppheaderStyle(element) {
    element.css({
        'background-color': 'orange',
        'color': '#FFFFFF'
    });
}

function createEvents() {
    $('div[id^="header"]').click(function () {
        if (currentOpenContent000 == $(this).attr('id').replace('header', 'content'))
            return;

        //hide old item
        setNormalsppheaderStyle($('#' + currentOpenContent000.replace('content', 'header')));
        $('#' + currentOpenContent000).animate( { width: '0' }, 500 );

        var cHeader = $(this).attr('id');
        var cContent = $(this).attr('id').replace('header', 'content');

        //show new item
        setSelectedsppheaderStyle($(this));
        $('#' + cContent).animate( { width: '400px' }, 500 );
        currentOpenContent000 = cContent;

    });

    $('div[id^="header"]').mouseover(function () {
        setHoversppheaderStyle($(this));
    });

    $('div[id^="header"]').mouseout(function () {
        if (currentOpenContent000 == $(this).attr('id').replace('header', 'content'))
            return;
        setNormalsppheaderStyle($(this));
    });
}

function initializeControl() {
    var first = $('#content1');
    first.show().animate( { width: '400px' }, 500 );
    currentOpenContent000 = 'content1';
    setSelectedsppheaderStyle($('#header1'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great. I was using animate before but like this - animate({ width: 'toggle' }, time) and it dint work.

Comment: Sorry. When I put the content inside the accordion this logic won't work as the div width will no longer be 0px. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay I fixed it by setting the div width to be explicitly to 0px. But when the animation goes to 0px to hide an accordion the content is moving inside it (which is very ugly) trying to fit inside the (reducing) width. Instead of that can we do a slide left or something?

Comment: I'm also stuck with a different problem for which I'm trying different fixes but not able to get it done. When an accordion item is clicked and when the content is opening and if you click another item simultaneously the divs overflow and get broken and come underneath. How to fix that?

Comment: Maybe that can be fixed by using already written jQuery accordions? Like http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-horizontal-accordion/ or http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html or http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion ...

Answer (score 0):

Since in IE the data in content boxes somehow overlaps I had to add the hide and show functions next to the animate instructions

$('#' + currentOpenContent000).hide('1000');
before:
$('#' + currentOpenContent000).animate( { width: '0' }, 600 );

and

$('#' + cContent).show();
after:
$('#' + cContent).animate( { width: '460px' }, 600 );